# BlobUrl not working when added as src in an audio source

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-audio

I am trying to play an audio on click but unfortunately it's not working
The response returns a binary which I did use base64_decode(responseFromServer);

And from the frontend(Vue) I am using axios and set it to receive a responseType of 'blob' with headers Content-Type: 'application/json'

I pass the response to axios like this

```
// inside audioPlay click method
// this is inside .then(response => )
const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {
      type: 'audio/wav',
}));

const audio = document.getElementById(`audio-${id}`);
const source = document.getElementById(`source-${id}`);

source.src = blobUrl;
audio.pause();
audio.load();
audio.oncanplaythrough;
audio.play();
```

And the template

```
<v-btn icon @click="audioPlay(item.audio_id)">
    <v-icon>mdi-play</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<audio :id="'audio-' + `${item.audio_id}`" class="d-none" controls>
    <source :id="'source-'+`${item.audio_id}`" src="" type="audio/wav"/>
</audio>
```

But unfortunately nothing happens, no sound at all.

Comment: What does `console.log(response.data)` outputs? If it's really a Blob, then no need to wrap it in an other one. Are you sure the data received is a proper audio file?

Comment: Yes it returns a proper blob, and I have another method that does download the file as .wav and it plays completely fine

Comment: Blob {size: 77605, type: "text/html"}
size: 77605
type: "text/html"
__proto__: Blob

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment rather than an answer, but it ended up being a long comment.

So I think the main problem you have is the request you are making. According to the response that you added in your comment, it says that the type of the Blob is `text/html`. I'm guessing since you want the actual audio file this is incorrect.

I think you might need to change a bit the request options you're passing to axios. Since you are requesting an audio file try changing the `Content-Type` header from `application/json` to `audio/mpeg`. Also, usually when requesting Blobs in axios the request `responseType` is set to `'arraybuffer'` as not setting it, axios will process the response as JSON as that is the default. (Reference to the axios config object: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

I think you need something like:

```
const response = await axios.get(url, {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
  }
});

// then create object URL from response...
```

**Update - Browser Audio Autoplay Policies**

Also, from the code that you shared it looks like you are trying to autoplay an audio after you made a request. This *might* not work due to the policies that browsers have nowadays. I don't know what browser you are using for testing, but for example on Chrome you need the user to at least interact with your page before sound starts playing. It's just good to keep this policy in mind when using audio.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes